# What is a land and hold short clearance (LAHSO)?

Tags: faa-regulations, landing

I was reading [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3109/can-you-accept-a-lahso-on-your-private-pilot-checkride) and I want to know what this term means.

> land and hold short clearance

Comment: also related http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1967/can-you-go-around-with-lahso-in-effect

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It means that you can land on the runway but must hold short (read: do not cross) before some point on the runway.

> [AIM 4-3-11 Pilot Responsibilities When Conducting Land and Hold Short Operations (LAHSO)](http://www.faraim.org/aim/aim-4-03-14-199.html)
>
> 6. A pilot who accepts a LAHSO clearance should land and exit the runway at the first convenient taxiway (unless directed otherwise) before reaching the hold short point. Otherwise, the pilot must stop and hold at the hold short point.

This is generally issued for smaller planes that don't need the full runway and a crossing runway/taxiway is also being used.

As the pilot you have final say in accepting the clearance, if you feel you will be unable to hold short then you should reply "unable" and request full-length landing clearance.

> [same link as above]
>
> 3. The pilot-in-command has the final authority to accept or decline any land and hold short clearance. The safety and operation of the aircraft remain the responsibility of the pilot. Pilots are expected to decline a LAHSO clearance if they determine it will compromise safety.

Comment: Nice answer. I might add two more points for completeness: A pilot with a LAHSO clearance [may still go around](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1967/can-you-go-around-with-lahso-in-effect?lq=1) per [AIM 4-3-11(b)(5)](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim/aim0403.html#aim0403.html.13); and student pilots should not accept a LAHSO clearance per [AIM 4-3-11(b)(2)](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim/aim0403.html#aim0403.html.13). Of course, a pilot should read the AIM section completely before accepting a LAHSO.

Comment: For those that may be reading this in the future, the FAA unfortunately killed their HTML versions of the FAR/AIM, so the links in the above comment are dead. The FAA now has a [PDF version of the AIM](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim_basic_4-03-14.pdf) and faraim.org [now publishes an HTML version](http://www.faraim.org/aim/aim-4-03-14-199.html).